# Can I use S3 as a shared, standalone, work queue?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, queue

I have a set of files in an S3 bucket and I'd like to have multiple clients process the files by downloading and deleting them so they can be processed locally.

How can I ensure that only one client can access any single file so exactly one worker download and processes it? I know I can introduce an additional queuing system or other external process to implement some kind of FIFO queue or locking mechanism, but I'm really hoping to minimize the number of components here so it's simply

(file_generation -> S3 -> workers) without adding more systems to manage or things that might break.

So is there any way to obtain a lock on a file or somehow atomically tag it for a single worker such that other workers will know to ignore it? Perhaps renaming the object's key with the worker's ID so it's "claimed" and no one else will touch it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a filestore like a queue?  Why not use a queue?  (*From your question, it sounds like you are being lazy!*).

If you want to keep a similar workflow, create a file on S3 and post the URI of the file to the queue (this can be done automatically by AWS).

Queues can have multiple consumers and there will never be any conflicts (normally).

Comment: Because the files can be large and the process is already using S3 so introducing another component to manage a queue just adds complexity that I'm trying to avoid. But thanks for insulting me!

Comment: That 'locking' thing you want to do, that's complex to get right?  That's where a queue simplifies things.   No need for anything complicated.  Reading a queue is easy.

Comment: I get that, but I'd like to be able to simply put a file in a bucket and have it get picked up and processed by a single worker without also having to add to a separate queue. It creates issues like what if an entry in the queue gets lost and the file remains, or files need requeued, or the queue goes offline, or objects get renamed, etc. If I could atomically get and delete a file from s3, all my worries would be solved and the bucket would be the definitive source of "work items".

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure that only one client can access any single file so exactly one worker download and processes it?

By using a queue, such as an Amazon SQS queue:

- Create an SQS queue
- Configure the S3 bucket to automatically send a message to the queue when a new object is created
- Configure your workers to poll the SQS queue for messages.
- When they receive a message, the message is temporarily made 'invisible' but is not removed from the queue
- When the worker has completed their process, they delete the message from the SQS queue

It meets your requirements 100% and works "out-of-the-box". Much more reliable than writing your own process.

> what if an entry in the queue gets lost and the file remains

Amazon SQS supports the concept of an *invisibility period* while messages are being processed, but are not fully processed. If a worker fails to delete the message after processing, the message will reappear on the queue after a defined period, ready for another worker to process it.

> or the queue goes offline

Amazon SQS is a *regional service*, which means that the queues are replicated between multiple Availability Zones, operated by parallel servers.

> or objects get renamed

It is not possible to 'rename' objects in Amazon S3. An object would need to be **copied** and the original object **deleted**.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but for future readers, you should use Amazon S3 Event Notifications:

**Solution 1 (Preferred)**

PutObject X -> [Optional] SNS Fanout -> SQS -> Lambda -> (on-failure) Dead Letter Queue [DLQ]

I know you want to avoid extra components, but this is probably your best bet, especially since:

a) DLQ redrives are supported in console now. Network issues caused a Lambda to fail? All it takes is a click of a button to redrive the messages back to the source queue (where the Lambda will automatically pick it up). And if you're dealing with large files, this will probably happen more often than you'd like.

b) You can batch messages in the queue, and handle multiple files per Lambda invocation easily instead of spinning up 100 concurrent invocations if you get a burst of 100 files.

**Solution 2**

Send the S3 event notification directly to Lambda, and have some cron job periodically check for stale files that are older than X (implying they failed to be processed since they weren't deleted). Still, you should at least use a DLQ for the Lambda here to make sure you don't lose information. I would strongly discourage this approach if you're not using compute with support for some sort of robust failure handling mechanism like Lambda has with DLQ's